# dropzone.js and ajax call = empty $_FILE, $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send form variables to PHP via AJAX and show the result in `console.log`. But the console shows always no value for data. I don´t know what's wrong. What I have so far:

**Part of jQuery Code:**

```
...
init: function() {
    this.on('success', function(csvFile, json) {
        // AJAX 
        $.ajax({
            url : "tests.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : this.csvFile
        }).done(function (data) {
            // Bei Erfolg
            console.log("Erfolgreich:" + data);
        }).fail(function() {
            // Bei Fehler
            console.log("Fehler!");
        }).always(function() {
            // Immer
            console.log("Beendet!");
        });
    });
```

**Part of HTML Code:**

```
<form action="tests.php" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
    <input type="text" name="testname" value="das bin ich"/>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $test = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    echo test;
}

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $test2 = $_POST['testname'];
    echo $test2;
}
```

Comment: what is on `this.csvFile` that you are trying to pass?

Comment: Please add `print_r($_POST);` in the top of the php file, so we'll be sure there is an output, and check if there was POST datas received.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code and PHP works fine (just need to fix "echo test" to "echo $test" in your tests.php).  Dropzone automatically attach itself to anything with class "dropzone" and it will do ajax requests to your server after you select a file.

If you want to programmatically:

HTML

```
<div id="myDZ">
  Drop your file
  <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="hello_world"/>
  <button id="upload">upload</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#upload").click(function(e){
          myDZ.processQueue();
        })
        var myDZ = new Dropzone("#myDZ", { 
             url: "tests.php",
             autoProcessQueue: false,
             init: function(){
                 this.on('sending', function(xhr, fd1, fd2){
                     //append extra data here
                     fd2.append("testname", $("#testname").val());
                 });    

                 this.on('success', function(file, responseText){
                   //do after successful upload
                   console.log(responseText);
                 })
               }
         });
 </script>
```

you can remove "autoProcessQueue: false" and remove the button stuff if you want it to auto upload once a file is selected.

more events can be found here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list